# is it a good way for playing video?

Tags: android, video

I want to play a video in a `VideoView`. I searched and found this:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
+ R.raw.your_raw_file);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
setContentView(videoHolder);
videoHolder.start();
```

which plays video from raw folder.
but one has tested my app on Galaxy s 3, android 4.1.2 and reported that app gets force closed. may the above code cause such problem or that works well on 4.1.2, too?
my video format is mp4, H264 AC

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    public static void getVideoFromRaw(String rawPath) {

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(mContext);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri mVideo = Uri.parse(rawPath);
        mVideoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        mVideoview.setVideoURI(mVideo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    mVideoview.requestFocus();
    mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mVideoview.start();

        }
    });

    mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps.